# wrong configuration of maven war plugin

Tags: spring, maven

I'm a basic maven user and I'm trying to copy the resources folder into the war file created by maven. I need to do this in order to be able to import css files into my jsp files. These are the relevant parts of my configuration files:

servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

pom.xml

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
        <web-resources>
        <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.css</include>
        </includes>
        </resource>
        </web-resources>
        <outputDirectory>../../tomcat/webapps</outputDirectory> 
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

jsp file:

```
<header>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">
</header>
```

resources structure:

- resources 
  -- css 
  style.css

I've spotted that the css folder is actually copied into the classes folder, but even changing the import path into the jsp file I'm not able to correctly load the css file. To launch the install I simply issue: `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default configuration of the war plugin will copy your resources into the root of your WAR.  I recommend just leaving the plugin without any additional configuration, and adjusting your mapping.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <targetPath>/css/</targetPath>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
          <directory>src/main/resources/css</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/deployments</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This will put your `css` folder into `/css` in your war, then you just configure your mapping as such.

```
<mvc:resources location="/css" mapping="/resources/css"></mvc:resources>
```

Comment: just tried with no configuration for the plugin and it still put the css folder under WEB-INF/classes/css. Besides that I do really need to keep the outputDirectory part of the configuration

Comment: @GJCode Ok, you can leave the `outputDirectory` in place, it specifies where your final war file is placed.  If you must have these resources at the root level, follow the convention of the war plugin.  All static resources for the webapp should be in `src/main/webapp`.  Moving your resources into this location will automatically add them to the root of the war.  That said, see my updates to the answer to see a configuration that will places anything in `src/main/resources/css` into `/css`